# Email notification when Kafka producer and consumer goes down

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have developed a data pipeline using Kafka. Right now I have one type of producer and two types of consumers setup in the cluster.

1. Producer: gets the message from a windows server
2. Consumer: Consumer A uses Spark Streaming to transform and present a real time view. Consumer B stores the RAW data, might be useful for building the schema at a later stage.

For various reasons starting from network, the consumers do not receive any data and also it is possible that the consumer process might die in case there is a system failure.

I would be interested in knowing if there is a way to implement something which sends you email notification when the consumer stops receiving messages or the consumer thread dies altogether. Do Kafka or Zookeeper provide a way of doing it?

Right now I am thinking of checking the target system if it is receiving messages or not. But in future if the number of targets increase it will be really complex to write email notification systems for individual targets.

Comment: Not sure if this 100% what you are looking for but you could try out https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow - it supports tracking consumer lag and email notifications if something goes wrong

Comment: @serejja thanks! that looks good.

Comment: Why don't you add this thing in your consumer/producer code itself.

Comment: @Bector2   but in longer run when this pipeline is facilated as a org wide service, it may not be a good idea to ask every one to add this in their code, possible but it will lead to some other issues, this is a feature separate from consumers/ producers and should not be tightly coupled.

Comment: you can make it configurable from property file from where you can add multiple mail id as per your need. In case of configuring in KAFKA you still have add these mail ids anyway. As far as i know Producer, Consumer and Brokers are independent component and hence there can not be a single point from where you can monitor all of three.

Comment: @Bector2 But in the zookeeper log I can see when a consumer/ producer getting connected and disconnected. I think zookeeper should be having this information with it.